# Simple Android Layout Issue - Pinch image effect to work beyond its layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

i want to use the pinch effect to zoom in and zoom out of an image. i'm able to zoom out the image (that is make the image smaller within the frame) but i'm unable to zoom in (that is extend the frame may be programmatically?

new on android, so dont have that thorough knowledge of layouts.
i used a github library Zoomage however i'm not too sure how to extend the image frame such that it exceeds the bounds and zooms further than that..

what i'm trying to do can be visually seen here

[this image shows what i want to do, the red arrows represent the area outside frame where i'd like to zoom to, while black border in the layout itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb1pt.jpg)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qen6cqs3u0cq2n1/demo.mov?dl=0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
.......some other layouts here
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="378dp"
    android:layout_height="341dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="107dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-4dp">

    <com.jsibbold.zoomage.ZoomageView
        android:id="@+id/songImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:zoomage_animateOnReset="true"
        app:zoomage_autoCenter="true"
        app:zoomage_autoResetMode="UNDER"
        app:zoomage_maxScale="8"
        app:zoomage_minScale="0.6"
        app:zoomage_restrictBounds="false"
        app:zoomage_translatable="true"
        app:zoomage_zoomable="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="93dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used  library Zoomage but, AFAIK TouchImageView is best libray I have used.

What you can do is:

Create a TouchImageView.class file with following code.

[Download the TouchImageView.class From here](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java)

Your ImageView in your layout as :

```
 <com.example.YourApp.TouchImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/iv_touchImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

and While initializing your ImageView in your Activity do this::

```
TouchImageView selectedImage =findViewById(R.id.iv_touchImageView);
selectedImage.setImageBitmap(yourBitmap);
```

Comment: this looks really good, let me try, would i be able to extend the zoom beyond the layouts size? because thats what i want to do? the pinch zoom feature is added via zoomage but the only trouble is the layout...its like not going beyond the layouts size?

let me try your solution and thanks!
will message shortly again if this sorts it out.

again the main issue is going beyond the layout when zooming in, like in the video shared. its more to do with layout i think than it is to do with library?

Comment: Well if you mean to extend the layout while the image is being zoom in then above solution will not help. But TouchImageView library can help you with zoom in and zoom out within the layout itself.